# How to use a subquery while performing left join in magento

Tags: sql, join

I want my query to filter only distinct `product_id` from the table `catalog_category_product` . The raw sql query goes like this :

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity AS catalog_category_table 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(product_id),category_id FROM catalog_category_product GROUP BY product_id) catalog_category_product_table ON catalog_category_product_table.category_id = catalog_category_table.entity_id
```

can anyone suggest how to write the sub query while performing the left join magento way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do something like this:

```
$subquery = new Zend_Db_Expr("( 
    SELECT DISTINCT(product_id), category_id 
    FROM `catalog_category_product` 
    GROUP BY product_id
)");
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        $subquery, 
        't.category_id = e.entity_id'
    );
```